# Leaflet.MarkerCluster not found function spiderfy()

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

i use angular and leaflet, for the cluster i use leaflet.markerCluster library but all method explain on github page give error function not found. I have include the script and the style in angular.json file, the library was installed with npm. Work only for basic use: create a marker and push in cluster with addLayer. But if i need spiderfy() invoked over L.markerCluster object i receive error function not exist.
this is some code:

Creation

```
  private markerCluster;
        this.markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({
      showCoverageOnHover: false
    });
```

ADD TO MAP

```
this.map.addLayer(this.markerCluster);
```

add markers in a loop

```
var marker = this.createMarker(point);

this.markerCluster.addLayer(marker);
```

if i invoke goes error

```
this.markerCluster.spiderfy();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`spiderfy`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/README.md#other-clusters-methods) is a method for a specific *cluster*, whereas in your code you are trying to invoke it on your Marker Cluster *Group*.

Current MCG behaviour is to spiderfy only one cluster at a time, that is why trying to spiderfy the entire group makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, so i need to take a cluster from the group and after call the method. There is a method to get this?

Comment: "_so i need to take a cluster from the group and after call the method_": yes that is correct. As for the method, I do not think there is something out-of-the-box, since it depends on what behaviour you wish to implement exactly. E.g. [`zoomToShowLayer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/README.md#other-group-methods) zooms to the given layer (marker), spiderfying if necessary already). Otherwise, you can directly read the `__parent` property added by MCG to your markers. Feel free to open a new question should you need help on implementing your desired behaviour.